# Toggle a draggable window using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to toggle on and off (hide and show) the draggable window (not the draggable functionality itself). I am not quite sure how to do so. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=bT5ziAnb3R)

I am not quite sure how to have the JQuery UI draggable widget on fiddle either. Anyway, if any of you have a idea that would be very helpful!
Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an old drag/drop [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1xnmtyqs/7/) I did some time ago - just added a few lines of JS to the top.

JS

```
$('.toggleme').on('click', function(){
   $('.dragme').toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: It looks great on your fiddle! I think It is exactly what I am trying to achieve but for some reasons, it does not work. Here is my [script](http://134.186.111.22/AG_Sandbox/layout-master/demos/Map-Widget.html). I am trying to toggle the inset map at the top right of the map. The inset should be draggable. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Thank you, Alex

Comment: Just made it work! That was it! Thank you! Is it possible to move the draggable window at initial position too?

Comment: Ok I will check how to do this with css. Is it possible to have the toggle window hidden onload?

Comment: You're going to have to figure out your logic in showing and moving the window. You can use the jQuery .hide() on load, then have it appear with a click do .show. Or you could do it with opacity/visibility/display - but you should think the logic out and put all the steps together...less coding/code in the end.